# Is the image of a scaled unit ball equal to the scalar times image of unit ball?

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Let T be a normed linear operator from X to Y. (The spaces, X,Y, can be just normed spaces, or Banach/ Hilbert space. I don't think it really matters too much). The question is whether $T(B(0,R))=RT(B(0,1))$ where $B(0,1)$ is the open ball of distance 1 around 0. I thought the equality was suppose to be obvious, but I'm not completely sure now.

Comment: Review the definition of "linear".  Can you apply that to prove your equation?

Comment: Hint: for a vector $v$ we have $v = \|v\| \frac {v}{\|v\|}$. Can you apply linearity here?

Comment: @GEdgar, ok i got it now. I thought we needed some extra injectivity or surjectivity conditions, but it looks like they weren't necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well of course this is true by a direct calculation: let $y\in T(B(0,R))$, so $y=Tx$ for some $x\in X$ with $\|x\|<R$. Then $\|\frac{x}{R}\|<1$ so $\frac{y}{R}=\frac{1}{R}Tx=T(\frac{x}{R})\in T(B(0,1))$ and thus $y\in R\cdot T(B(0,1))$. This shows the one inclusion. Conversely, if $y=R\cdot Tx$ for some $x\in X$ with $\|x\|<1$, then $y=T(Rx)$ and $\|Rx\|=R\|x\|<R$, so $y\in T(B(0,R))$ and this shows the other inclusion.